# Quarkus xml Parser DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found, but only when using quarkus-run.jar

Tags: maven, quarkus, optaplanner

When packaging our app with `mvn package` everything works fine. Then when we start our app with `java -jar target\quarkus-app\quarkus-run.jar` the app silently crashes. While debugging we found that it crashes while parsing an xml InputStream. It happens while initialising some classes.
This is the stacktrace that we had to dig out ourselves:

```
Exception occurred in target VM: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be found
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.io.jaxb.GenericJaxbIO.parseXml(GenericJaxbIO.java:209)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.io.jaxb.SolverConfigIO.read(SolverConfigIO.java:15)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlReader(SolverConfig.java:199)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlInputStream(SolverConfig.java:173)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlInputStream(SolverConfig.java:160)
```

When packaging the app in an uberjar this problem does not occur. Same when using dev.
We use graalvm-ce-java17-22.2.0, together with the 2.11.2.Final version of quarkus and the 8.29.0.Final version of optaplanner.

We tried to verify that there aren't any xml exclusion in the dependencies. Also we checked if quarkus and the quarkus maven-compiler-plugin are of the same version. Also we looked into the compiled jarfiles, if the xml we want to read is present. If it wouldn't be present, the code would crash even earlier. The class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory is not listed in the quarkus-app-dependencies.txt

Comment: Are you using the the [quarkus-optaplanner extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner)?

Comment: So i included quarkus-optaplanner-bom in the dependency management and then it told me that some logback dependencies are not compatable. After removing the logback dependencies in the pom.xml it builds as it did before (with `mvn package`).
Now when running `quarkus-app.jar` the same error occurs, but now it doesn't crash silently anymore, which was apparently caused by some logback dependency mismatches.

So atleast some logging stuff is fixed now. Thanks

Comment: I have added the optaplanner tag since I think that this might not directly quarkus-related, but somewhere in the integration between quarkus and optaplanner. You could also try asking via the [optaplanner dev group](https://groups.google.com/g/optaplanner-dev).

Comment: This is a very hard guess: you could try adding `quarkus-jaxp` to the dependencies. This might include a bean for the `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

Comment: At the moment, I can not imagine how this could be a bug in OptaPlanner. However, if you provide a simplified Maven project that exhibits this behavior, I will look into it further.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the [quarkus-optaplanner extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/optaplanner) helped to identify the logger issue. So the problem with the silent crash is resolved. Adding `quarkus-jaxp` to the dependencies gets rid of the `FactoryConfigurationError` and everything works as expected.

Comment: Could you create a Quarkus issue with a small Maven reproducer? I would like to have a look at it. It should work out of the box.